# Why yum always download fedora 22 -x86_x64 before install anything?

Tags: fedora

Every time I try to install something by `yum`, `yum` always download something below:

```
Fedora 22 - x86_64 - 51% [==========          ] 9.6 kB/s | 6.9 MB     11:38 ET
```

Is there anything wrong with `yum` or Fedora ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum is  simply updating its package database. Maybe this happens because you install packages not too often.

Note that if you have fedora 22, you should use

```
$ dnf install a_package
```

instead of the deprecated

```
$ yum install a_package
```