# Why I can not update Fedora 22?

Tags: fedora, yum, upgrade

Similar question as here [Why yum always download fedora 22 -x86_x64 before install anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225165/why-yum-always-download-fedora-22-x86-x64-before-install-anything)

In my case it happen whatever I try to do with `yum` or `dnf`. When the downloading process is running it never ends, because it always freezes at 49% percent and return to 27% and go on as a loop, so actually I can not install new packages. I've tried `yum clean all`, but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting network timeouts or any other errors?  If you want to debug the dnf process, try adding a '-d9' to the command line argument.

You might also want to look at the [Fedora MirrorManager](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/mirrors/Fedora/22/x86_64) page to find a local mirror, and update your /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora*.repo files.